# Magento 2.2.1 export products all store views

Tags: magento-2.1, multistore

just tried to do an export of all products from all store views. But it just does export the Default products. Do I miss something? Any idea how to export all the products?
Thanks.

Comment: I'm having this exact issue. Did you find any solution?

Comment: Found your issue in GitHub: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/12356. Still broken though :(